# Неполадки с Atlas

Tags: spritekit, xcode, objective-c, ios7

Создал папку Rad.atlas, закинул туда текстуры, разрешение на превышает 2000X2000, но при компилировании XCode выдаёт предупреждение: /TextureAtlas: Splitting 'Rad.atlas' into 2 texture atlases due to input texture dimensions.
Что это значит и как решить?

Comment: Суммарный размер текстур чему равняется?

Comment: Одна - 772x780, всего 5 текстур.

Comment: В общем я уменьшил текстуры, так, чтобы их суммарный размер не превышал 2000x2000, и всё получилось.